# Is direct image of simple $D$-module is also simple?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, d-modules

(I have asked the question
[The commutativity of minimal extension $\cdots$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/301134/the-commutativity-of-minimal-extension-and-direct-image-by-blowing-down) and I simplify this question to the next simple question:)

Let $X$ be a rational variety over $\mathbb{C}$, $\phi : \hat{X} \rightarrow X$ be the blow-up of one point $\{p\}$, and $M$ be a simple (holonomic) $D_{\hat{X}}$-module.
Then

*Is it true that the direct image $\int_{\phi}M (=\phi_+M)$ is also simple (holonomic) $D_X$-module ?*

Comment: I'm not a $D$-module expert but I'm pretty sure the answer is no. If you take a $D$-module $M$ supported on the special fiber you should get the simple module supported at $p$ tensored with the cohomology of $M$, and already for $X$ a smooth surface, so the exceptional divisor is $\mathbb P^1$, the cohomology can be arbitrarily large.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. I’ll provide an example for what WillSawin suggested. Let $X$ be $\Bbb C^2$. Let $M$ be the irreducible holonomic module on $\hat X$ supported on the special fiber whose restriction to the special fiber is the structure sheaf. Then the direct image of $M$ is just the de Rham complex of $\Bbb P^1$, or rather the direct image of this complex via the (exact) functor $H^0i_+$, where $i\colon \{0\}\to X$ is inclusion. In particular, $\phi_+M$ has cohomology in more than one degree.

Comment: Thank you very much.
I am a beginner of $D$-module, so I cannot understand what do you mean by ''$\phi_+M$ has cohomology in more than one degree", and why this implies that $\phi_+M$ is not simple...

I would be grateful if you would give me more explanation.

Comment: @YukiMatsubara This means that it’s not a module, it’s a complex. It has cohomology in more than one degree (I don’t know how else to phrase that part). In order for it to be a simple *module* it needs to actually be, well, a *module*.